# How to determine the eigenvalue?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

I have this question:

> Let $\{u_1, u_2, u_3, u_4\}$ be a basis for $\mathbb{R}^4$
> and $B$ a $4 \times 4$ matrix such that:
> $$
> Bu_1=u_2,~~ Bu_2=u_1,~~ Bu_3=u_4,~~ Bu_4=u_3.~~
> $$
> Find ***all*** eigenvalues of $B$
> and determine whether $B$ is diagonalizable.
> Justify your answers.

<sup>[[image of problem statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ox6ho.png)]</sup>

I am having troubles identifying all the eigenvalues of
the matrix $B$ described in
this question.

I believe that one of the eigenvalues is $-1$, which can be obtained from $$\begin{eqnarray}
               Bu_1 - Bu_2 &=& u_2 - u_1 \\
\Rightarrow~~  B(u_1 -u_2) &=& u_2 - u_1
\end{eqnarray}$$

The above can be true only if $\lambda = -1$. 
This is the same for the $Bu_3 - Bu_4 = u_4 - u_3$

I can't seem to determine the rest or prove that this is the only eigenvalue.

Comment: Try $u_1+u_2$                   .

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please type your questions rather than posting images. Images can't be browsed, and are not accessible to those using screen readers. If you need help formatting math on this site, [here's](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) a tutorial To begin with, surround all math expressions (including numbers,) with `$` signs. Use ^ for exponents and _ for subscripts. `$x_1^{2/3}$` shows up as $x_1^{2/3}$.

Comment: You may want to check eigenvalues of a permutation matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Relative to the given basis,  the matrix is  $M=\begin  {pmatrix}0&1&0&0\\1&0&0&0\\0&0&0&1\\0&0&1&0\end{pmatrix} $.

Now find the roots of the characteristic polynomial: $\rm {det}(M-xI) $.

Get $x^2(x^2-1)+(1-x^2)=x^4-2x^2+1=(x+1)^2 (x-1)^2$.

Thus the eigenvalues are $\pm1$.

Comment: Sorry, how did you derive matrix M?

Comment: Applied the transformation to the basis vectors,  expressed in terms of themselves.   Which is to say to the standard basis.   Then expressed the results in terms of that same basis.